# How to test a controller's function that it is not associated to an URL (components of symfony1)?

Tags: symfony

I found the way to test an action in symfony2, for example this way:

```
public function testShow()
{
    $client = $this->createClient();
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/about');
    $this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->getStatusCode() == '200' );
    $this->assertTrue($crawler->filter('title:contains("About")')-> >count() > 0);
    $this->assertTrue($crawler->filter('h2:contains("About")')-> >count() > 0);
}
```

As you can see the action that it's been tested is associated to a URL
(/about), but how to test a controller's function that it is not
associated to an URL (components of symfony1) ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an _internal route you could use. But if you use {% render 'Something' %} then it would be in the rendedren content of other controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your contoroller [as a service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html) and test it.

Or just create it as plain php object and set container via `->setContainer()`